# How CAN acts in listen only mode?

Tags: can-bus

If a CAN module is configured to listen only mode, does it make the ACK bit dominant for the Tx Node to acknowledge that the message has been successfully received? If the receiver node doesn't send an ACK bit, what can be done to the Tx node to continue sending the data? Consider two nodes on this private bus. The Tx node is manipulating a message received from BCM that will be sent on a private bus and the receiver is in Listen only mode.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is _not_ using listen only mode an option? Then the second device will just send out the ACK bits. A node that complies with the CAN standard just is not allowed to send in certain conditions, e.g. if the ACKs are missing for several messages in a row. You can probably change that behavior by adapting the firmware of a controller, but then its no longer CAN but something close to that.